# how to setup a firebase listview search

Tags: android, firebase, listview, search, chat

I'm making a chat app for a school project. and I am having trouble in the listview search function. So far I managed to search the users by their user names, but I am having trouble setting up a new intent to their profile activity my profile activity requires the firebase uid to pass it to the profile activity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and the code and not images of the code. Besides that, tell us what doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Im looking to pass the firebase uid to my profileactivity as an intent so that they can be redirected to the profile of the user they wish to add. problem is I cant seem to find a way to get the position and tie it to that user's uid.